# Multi-Series (Column) MySQL Query Won't Summarize Properly

Tags: mysql, graph, group-by, series

I have several years worth of data in a table (inquiries).  Every entry has a contact_time field that is the timestamp of their email contact.  I'm trying to build monthly or weekly summary data for plotting on a multi-series graph.  To that end, I need to see the month or week number in the first column with the respective data from 2014 in the second column, and from 2015 in the third column, etc.

```
SELECT MONTH(inquiries.contact_time) AS "Date",
(SELECT
    COUNT(inquiries.id) AS "Inquiries"
    FROM inquiries
    WHERE YEAR(inquiries.contact_time) = "2014"
) AS "2014",
(SELECT COUNT(inquiries.id) AS "Inquiries"
    FROM inquiries
    WHERE YEAR(inquiries.contact_time) = "2015"
) AS "2015"
FROM inquiries
GROUP BY MONTH(inquiries.contact_time)
```

All I'm seeing is the total count for each year in all of the rows.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the total count for the year because your subqueries are not related to the month for the outer query's grouping.

I would write the query this way:

```
SELECT MONTH(contact_time) AS `Date`,
  SUM(YEAR(contact_time)=2014) AS `2014`,
  SUM(YEAR(contact_time)=2015) AS `2015`
FROM inquiries
GROUP BY MONTH(contact_time)
```

Explanation: the COUNT() of a specific set of rows is the same as the SUM() of 1's for those rows. And MySQL boolean expressions return the integer 1 for **true**.

Comment: Much appreciated, that was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTH(i.contact_time),
       SUM(YEAR(i.contact_time) = 2014) as cnt_2014,
       SUM(YEAR(i.contact_time) = 2015) as cnt_2015
FROM inquiries i
WHERE YEAR(i.contact_time) >= 2014
GROUP BY MONTH(i.contact_time);
```

If you have an index on `contact_time`, then use the condition `where i.contact_time >= '2014-01-01'`, so it can take advantage of the index.